# join and where in deep associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have Projects, which have many Users, and that users have many partners. so associations would look like that:

Project: has_many: users 
User: belongs_to: project, has_many: partners 
Partner: belongs_to: user

So now i whant to join those three clases, get data by partner id's and then serialize everything. 
result should look like this, if i search for partner id= 1,2:

```
result = {project.id:1, user.id:1, partner.id:1},
{project.id:1, user.id:1, partner.id:2},
{project.id:1, user.id:2, partner.id:1},
{project.id:2, user.id:1, partner.id:1}
```

p.s. result variable doesn't have to have all that joined information, information should be returned through serializer.

so here is how i tried to do that:

```
projects = Project.joins(:users, :partners).where(partners: { partner_id: ids })
```

after serializer this returns project with user and all partners instead of one that id is equal what i have searched.

Also tried another way, but it won't work at all, i get error:

```
projects = Project.joins(:users, :partners).where(users: {partners: { partner_id: ids }})
```

In only one association if i need to search by user id it works well :

```
projects = Project.joins(:users).where(users: { user_id: ids })
```

Any idea how to get all projects with all users and all partners, that partner id is equal to searched one?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I have tried nested joint, but it doesn't work also :

```
projects = Project.joins(users: :partner).where(partners: { partner_status_id: ids })
```

here is the result SQL:

```
SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."partner_id" = "projects"."id" INNER JOIN "partners" ON "partners"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "partners"."partner_status_id" = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can just try using add one association as

```
class Project 
   has_many :partners, :through => :users
end
```

And your query as

```
  projects = Project.joins(:partners).where(partners: { partner_id: ids })
```